# iOS7 - can't view the storyboard as iOS6

Tags: ios6, ios7

There is an option in the utilities pane to view a layout of a screen as iOS 7 or iOS 6.1 and it worked for me when I was working on the iPhone storyboard. But when I switched to the iPad storyboard, the option for viewing it in iOS 6.1 is disabled. Here is a screen shot:

[image: Screenshot]

You see where the cursor is? It shows iOS 6.1 is disabled. Would anyone know how to enable that option?

Thank you!

EDIT:

And here are some settings for the project:

[image]

Comment: what's your deployment target?

Comment: @glasz I just added a screen shot with some settings to my original question.

Comment: just a wild guess, can't check right now: set your deployment target to something lower than 7.0 because when you deploy only to 7.0 your app won't run on 6.x anyway and thus an ios 6 storyboard-look doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @glasz oh very smart!!!! It worked! If you want to add that as the answer, I will accept :)

Answer (score 0):

set your **deployment target** to something lower than 7.0.
if  you deploy to 7.0 only, your app won't run on 6.x anyway and thus an ios 6 storyboard-look doesn't make any sense.

you may need to configure the deployment target both in your project *and* your storyboard/xib (info pane on the right).